# Is there a way to access values stored in has_many association in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models in Ruby on Rails, movies, and directors. A director has_many movies, and a movie belongs_to a director. I'm creating a mini-project, where if I view a Director on a page, I would like to have all movies associated with this particular author shown, along with links to these movies. I was able to make it with a movie successfully showing its Director with a link to his page, but I've been unable to accomplish this when viewing a director. All my research so far has led me to is

<%= director.movies.uniq.pluck(:name) %>

but that only shows the :name strings within an array format, which is not optimal. I would like to know if there is a way, in which I can access the id values stored in has_many. Because it has to work like an array, which saves the ids, so the program knows, which Movies belong to which Director. Please correct me if I'm wrong in this assumption, I'm still learning and will appreciate any input on this matter.

Comment: the id's of the movies: `director.movie_ids`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To accomplish this you will need to iterate over the array of `Movie` instances that belong to an instance of a `Director`. You can access this array (which is actually a [Collection Proxy](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html)) with `director.movies` (assuming that `director` is an instance of `Director`). You will then be able to access the values of each instance.

Your code may look something like this:

```
<ul>
  <% director.movies.each do |movie| %>
    <li><%= link_to movie.name, movie_path(movie) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! The links work perfectly, but for some reason, it now displays all values of linked movies in a format [#<Movie id: n, name: "Name", release_date:"yyyy-mm-dd", etc.>] behind said links, any idea what's causing that?

Comment: @chleba381 I'm thinking that you have maybe used an `<%=` instead of `<%` in front of `director.movies.each` - if not, can you show your code here?

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much!